# Using the same data dependently in the same useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to fetch my data in two different ways and render it according to this. At the first load, I need to fetch all the items one by one and increment the count. After that, I need to fetch all the data at once and update the display. So, I wrote something like this (not the actual code but almost the same thing):

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGlobalState } from "./state";

const arr = Array.from(Array(100), (x, i) => i + 1);

function App() {
  const [{ posts }, dispatch] = useGlobalState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInc = () => {
      arr.forEach(async id => {
        const res = await axios(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
        );
        dispatch({
          type: "INC",
          payload: res.data
        });
      });
    };

    const getAll = async () => {
      const promises = arr.map(id =>
        axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      );
      const res = await Promise.all(promises);
      dispatch({
        type: "ALL",
        payload: res.map(el => el.data)
      });
    };

    if (!posts.length) {
      getInc();
    } else {
      getAll();
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{posts.length}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm simply using `Context` and `useReducer` to create a simple store. The above code works as it is but I skip adding `posts.length` dependency and this makes me think that my logic is wrong.

I tried to use refs to keep track the initialization state but I need to track the data at every route change. Then, I tried to keep it by adding an `init` state to my store but I couldn't make it work without problems. For example, I can't find a suitable place to dispatch the `init`. If I try it after a single fetch it triggers the initialization immediately and my other function (`getAll`) is invoked.

If anyone wants to play with it here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-monad-402lb

Comment: Can you explain what your desired vs current behaviour is a bit more clearly?

Comment: Let me know which part is not clear and I'll try my best explaining it by updating my question. The above code works but React warns me to add `posts.length` to the dependency array of `useEffect`. But, if I add it the app enters a rendering loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `init` to your store:

```js
// @dataReducer.js
export const initialDataState = {
  init: true,
  posts: []
};

const dataReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ALL':
      // init false
      return { ...state, posts: action.payload };
    case 'INC':
      return { ...state, init: false, posts: [...state.posts, action.payload] };
...
}
```

```js
// @App.js
function App() {
  const [{ init, posts }, dispatch] = useGlobalState();

  useEffect(() => {
    init ? getInc(dispatch) : getAll(dispatch);
  }, [init, dispatch]);
...
}
```

[image: Edit funny-violet-pwew6]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually, I tried this. I should have mentioned it clearly in my question, sorry. When I add a `setInterval(() => getAll(dispatch), 10000);` to my effect it is triggered twice in every interval.

Comment: It sounds like out of scope the current question (The problem is with init or async rendering?), I think you should ask another question I'll be glad to help. (It's not clear "where" exactly and how you adding the interval)

Comment: Right below your `init ? getInc(dispatch) : getAll(dispatch);` line. If you want me to ask a new question I can do it of course.

Comment: Another note: such interval will overflow your app with threads.

Comment: I think you should... send me a link (your question is out of the scope)

Comment: What do you mean by threads? If I didn't need the incremental fetch it seems easy to me. I fetch the first data, display it and by intervals, I do the update. OK, I'm asking a new question.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56425989/data-initialization-in-useeffect-triggers-multiple-requests