# Data initialization in useEffect triggers multiple requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a follow-up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424826/using-the-same-data-dependently-in-the-same-useeffect).

Simply, I'm fetching the same date in two different ways. One by one and all together for updates. I have a simple store with context and `useReducer`.

My current code is like that:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGlobalState } from "./state";

const arr = Array.from(Array(100), (x, i) => i + 1);

function App() {
  const [{ posts, init }, dispatch] = useGlobalState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getInc = () => {
      arr.forEach(async id => {
        const res = await axios(
          `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`
        );
        dispatch({
          type: "INC",
          payload: res.data
        });
      });
    };

    const getAll = async () => {
      const promises = arr.map(id =>
        axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`)
      );
      const res = await Promise.all(promises);
      dispatch({
        type: "ALL",
        payload: res.map(el => el.data)
      });
    };

    if (init) {
      getInc();
    } else {
      getAll();
    }

    setInterval(() => getAll(), 10000);
  }, [dispatch, init]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{posts.length}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

In every interval `getAll` is triggered twice.[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-monad-402lb) is a working sandbox.

I added a `console.log` to reducer part so you can see it runs twice. I can also see it in the network tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Separate Concerns](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-use-multiple-effects-to-separate-concerns) when using `useEffect`, like you mentioned "One by one **and** all together for updates".

```js
function App() {
  const [{ init, posts }, dispatch] = useGlobalState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => getAll(dispatch), 10000);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    init ? getInc(dispatch) : getAll(dispatch);
  }, [init, dispatch]);
...
}
```

---

**Note:**

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    init ? getInc(dispatch) : getAll(dispatch);
  }, [init, dispatch]);
```

After `init` turns to `true`, `getAll` gets called twice, once from upcoming `interval` and one from the `useEffect` above.

So in summary, on your **Network**, first 3 post request intervals with ids `[0-99]` are:

1. from `getInc`
2. from `getAll` in `useEffect` with `init`
3. from `getAll` in `interval`

[image: Edit funny-violet-pwew6]

Comment: Excellent. I tried separate `useEffects` before but miscalculated the condition parts I guess.  Thank you so much.